# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: scala, pyspark

I'm getting below error:

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'"

Here's my code in pyspark:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile("/PATH/train.tsv")
val records = rawData.map(line => line.split("\t"))
val data = records.map(lambda line: line.map(lambda x: x.replace ("\"","")))
```

The error is at line 3, at "line.map" .

**Also, the corresponding scala line works fine without any issues:**

```
val data = records.map { r => r.map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))
```

It gives me the desired output.

(The dataset is downloaded from kaggle: http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data.)

Struggling with this since last two days. Pls help.

Thanks
gshweta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `.map` on the argument to your `lambda`.

Based on the preceding RDD transformations, the argument to `map`'s lambda expression is of type `list` (the result of `.split`).

You probably meant to code:

```
records.map(lambda line: list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\"",""), line)))
```

The difference is that the function `map` (`map(lambda x: x.replace("\"",""), line)`) is Python's built-in function (**and that's neither a `list` function - explaining the error you're getting - nor Spark's `RDD.map`**).

Comment: Great !! it worked fine...So lambda arguments are always treated as lists? Also is there any way to save the list as RDD in the lambda expression

Comment: Basically I want to have equivalent python code for this scala code: val data = records.map { r =>
          val trimmed = r.map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))
          val label = trimmed(r.size - 1).toInt
          val features = trimmed.slice(4, r.size - 1).map(d => if (d ==
                                  "?") 0.0 else d.toDouble)
          LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features))
}

Comment: The difference is that scala list/collection has a `.map` method, but Python's `list` doesn't have one (but Python gives you a built-in global method for that). So your call had to change. No, lambda arguments do **not** have to be lists, they are the type prior transformations returned (in this case, `line.split("\t")` returned a list, and that's why the following map's lambda had to take a list)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not parallelized the data before using map. Use below code:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile("/PATH/train.tsv")
val recordsParell=sc.parallelize(rawData)
val records = recordsParell.map(line => line.split("\t"))
```

sc.parallelize API will help in loading user created data which is not mandatorily coming from a directory.